# Options for a slow loading Webview

Tags: cocoa, webview

I have a Webview in a Cocoa application that essential shows a HTML table plus a few other items. The table can get very big, in the 10's of 1000's cells. When called the view takes a long time to load which seems to be just because of the size of the table that is being shown.

I'm looking to decrease the time it takes to show the view. The obvious 'quick and dirty' method of speeding this up is to show the table in sections with a link going forward and backwards through the sections of the table so only a smaller section of the table is shown at once. Is there a more elegant way of doing this that allows the whole of the table to be shown in the Webview at once or a way to incrementally load the table?

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that the data is shown in a `WebView`? Performance will be a LOT better if you use an `NSTableView` and populate it with data that you obtain via a web service.

`NSTableView` loads data lazily, so you never need to populate more than the number of cells that are actually visible.

Comment: I used to have an NSTableView for showing the data and I may have to go back to the table view. There are a few reasons I'm looking at a webview for things like alowing users to customise the format of the table so when they print reports it looks similar to how it looks on screen etc.